# Regex skipping lines

Tags: regex, pcre, skip

Here's my sample text and regex

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/svGxda/2)

I'd like to match text after Number, Category, "What is the specific role or function of this server?:", "Server Hostname:" etc. However the method I'm using now doesn't work well if the text used changes. I'd like this to be dynamic so that it can skip as many number of lines/characters as possible to reach the next match.

**I'm currently using the following regex:**

```
Number\:\s(?<Number>\d+)[\r\n]Category\:\s(?<Category>.*).*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n]What\sis\sthe\sspecific\srole\sor\sfunction\sof\sthis\sserver\?\:\s(?<Function>.*).*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n]Server\sHostname\:\s(?<Hostname>.*).*[\r\n]Server\sAllegiance\:\s(?<Domain>.*).*[\r\n].*[\r\n]Physical\sLocation\:\s(?<Location>.*).*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n]Local\sAdministrators\:\s+([\w\s]+)[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n]Task\sDescription\:\s(?<Task>.*)
```

I know, I know, it's ugly!

Comment: Which programming language? `PHP` ? `Python` ? And do you have other text samples? As of now, your pattern results in [**a catastrophic backtracking**](https://regex101.com/r/S2OqoV/1).

Comment: Your regex runs away with catastrophic backtracking. You could use the `|` operator te separate each named captured group.

Comment: Copying from S/O to R101 messed up the text somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[\r\n]Number\:\s(?<Number>\d+)|.*[\r\n]Category\:\s(?<Category>.*)[\r\n]|[\r\n]What.*specific.*\:\s(?<Function>.*)
```

etc...